# Express server can't fully interact with Firebase Storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-storage

So, storage.ref() works and storage.child("some.txt") works and returns a file refrence, i can get its name by **.name**. But I cant either get download link nor upload a file.
My config is as follows:

```
|-firebase
  |-firebase.js
  |-storage.js
|-index.js
```

```js
firebase.js:
    const firebase = require('firebase/app');
    global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    let firebaseStorage = require('firebase/storage');
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "abc", //real credentials are provided
      authDomain: "def", //real credentials are provided
      projectId: "xyz", //real credentials are provided
      storageBucket: "hi", //real credentials are provided
      messagingSenderId: "idk", //real credentials are provided
      appId: "some" //real credentials are provided
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    console.log('[FIREBASE] Firebase Init')


    module.exports = firebase;
```

And storage is just exporting firebase.storage(); nothing too much.
the problem here is:
this doesnt return anything and the whole code is stuck in this bit:

```js
  let fileRef = storageRef.child('myfile.txt');

  fileRef.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
    console.log('File available at: ', downloadURL);
    res.send(downloadURL);
  });
```

I spent alot of time trying to find simillar questions and using different libs for that but i cant find anything.

Comment: Is this in a cloud function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj What do you mean? Its in a nodejs enviroment

Comment: By Node you mean your own express server or are you using Firebase Cloud Functions?

Comment: @Dharmaraj ye node.js express server

Comment: So you want to upload files directly from server to firebase or `user -> server -> firebase` something like this?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes.

Comment: Which one? First or 2nd case?

Comment: I have already done it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase javascript modules were designed to work within a browser environment, for node.js it is suggested to use the admin sdk with limited credentials or [GCloud Node](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node). You can use this with your existing storage bucket and the typical Firebase setup.

To quote a Firebase Dev:

> Since Google Cloud Storage already provides a number of high-quality client libraries, we didn't want to reimplement another

Client environment: [GCP integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration)

Server environment: [Admin-sdk Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: Ok thanks but I need to use storage with authentication along with firebase in node js, i didnt find any way to do it in firebase-admin, for gcloud node, can you provide me with a good tutorial?

Comment: When using firebase-admin, it doesnt allow me to access firebase.storage().ref()

Comment: that is because firestore storage is not supported in node. You must rely on the GCloud solution https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration

Comment: If this is a server environment however, as in, the client doesn't use this. you cannot use the `firebase/app` as this is designed for front-end client use. please read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who came here trying to fix it, here is what I did.
I used firebase-admin and exported it to `var admin` (after init with serviceAcc)
then i did `var storage = admin.storage()` then got `@google-cloud/storage` Bucket instance with `storage.bucket()` now I can download, upload, and do everything `@google-cloud/storage` Bucket contains. Thanks for **@DIGI Byte** for helping me out